# How do I make a simple bidirectional current limiter

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-limiting, jfet, balancing

I want to connect two separate batteries together and let the highest voltage one charge the lower one not exceeding the desired current. I expect it to be a solid state solution without the need for programmable parts. I was looking for something in the range 1A-10A. It does not need to be adjustable, although I would like to make a 1A one and a 10A one, for example. The voltage difference  would be 4v maximum. I would like it to continue to work down to diode voltages.  When balanced it would need to draw only a low current maximum. Say < 1mA. Obviously resistors would do this job. I was hoping for a solution that would maintain a higher current as the voltages converged, would be more efficient and would not get too hot. Efficiency is not a deal breaker.

The following site suggests back to back JFETs but I cannot find any more references to such a circuit and its not clear to me what the typical components I could use and the magnitude of the current when limited. http://unitedsic.com/sic-jfets/

Would it be possible to use back to back constant current source circuits made from linear voltage regulators?

The aim is to get the batteries into a "storage" state where they are nether fully charged or discharged. At the moment I am charging the fully discharged batteries from a separate supply and discharging the unused fully charged batteries to a load. I can charge a discharged battery using a charged one. However to charger boosts the voltage so it can over discharge the battery I am using as a supply. The charger does not protect against this. It would be nice just to balance all the batteries. The final voltage is likely to be within the storage range.

Comment: Maybe a ptc could solve your problem?

Comment: Would I ask too much if I'd ask what do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Linear regulators tend to not be very happy if you force current backwards through them.

Comment: Updated with the reason. I would like to balance the battery voltages for storage.

Comment: Would a ptc settle to a constant current or will it switch on and off? (Only know of them being used as a fuse substitute.)

Comment: @BillyBag2 Sure, but I was hoping to know your goal. I understood that you want them to be not charged, not discharged, but for what purpose would you have them reach that level? What would it serve? Othwerise, a simple resistor between them will bring them to a slightly less average (losses&co).

Comment: If linear regulators were used then there would be two in parallel. The current would only flow through one of them. Not sure if they like reverse voltage or if they could be protected against this.

Comment: I want to prepare them for storage in a short time. Resistors would be exponential and would take too long. I do not want to store them connected to the circuit.

Comment: How short is short and how exponential should something not be given that resistors don't have diode volt drops and will therefore transfer energy much more effectively.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't understand what you mean about the diodes being worse. The resistors will have the voltage difference between the batteries across them. 4V to start with. At 1A that is 4w and at 10A that is 40W. If we take 0.7v as a guide end point the resistors for the 1A system will end up only drawing 0.175A. An ideal solution would draw 1A until 0.7v. As an example.